# Queue implementation in javolution

Tags: java, queue, javolution

Can anybody let me know is there any Queue implementation in [javolution](http://javolution.org/) to use? I have seen FastList, FastMap, FastTable, but I couldn't find one specific to Queue. Any other suggestion to have a fast queue usage please?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is a Queue implementation in Javolution.

Why not to use standard java.util.LinkedList or java.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue? Those are pretty efficient implementations of the Queue interface:

- http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html
- http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply, you are correct. I'm now using the FastTable wrapped up with my own class to use as the Queue implementation. I've compared the results, Fasttable is faster & time predictable against LinkedList :)

Comment: just for the the record: LinkedList is not a good implementation of Queue. ArrayDeque is.